# Natural Deduction Proof with Quantifiers Proof Validation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, quantifiers, natural-deduction

Only using natural deduction prove:

$$\frac{\forall x P(x) \\ \forall x \lnot Q(x) \lor \forall yQ(y) \\ \exists x [P(x) \rightarrow \lnot Q(x)]}{\therefore \forall x \lnot Q}$$

**My solution:**

$1. \space \forall x P(x) \qquad \qquad \qquad premise\\ 2. \space \forall x \lnot Q(x) \lor \forall y Q(y) \qquad premise\\ 3. \space \exists x [P(x) \rightarrow \lnot Q(x)] \qquad premise \\ \boxed{4. \space x_o \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad arbitrary \\ \boxed{5. \space y_o \space P(y_o) \rightarrow Q(y_o) \qquad assumption \\ 6. \space \lnot Q(x_o) \ \lor \forall yQ(y) \qquad \forall-elim(2,4) \\ 7. \space \lnot Q(x_o) \lor Q(y_o) \qquad \forall-elim(2,5) \\ \boxed{8.\space y_o\space Q(y_o) \qquad\qquad assumption \\ 9.\space \lnot Q(y_o) \qquad \qquad \rightarrow-elim(5)\\ 10. \space F \qquad \qquad \lnot-elim(8-9)\\ 11. \space \lnot Q(x_o) \qquad \qquad F-elim (10)}\\ \boxed{12. \space \lnot P(x_o) \qquad \qquad assumption \\ 13. \space P(x_o) \qquad \qquad \forall-elim(1,4) \\ 14. \space F \qquad \qquad \lnot-elim(12-13) \\ 15.\space \lnot Q(x_o) \qquad \qquad F-elim(15)}\\ 16. \space \lnot Q(x_o) \qquad \qquad \lor-elim (8-11,12-15)}\\17. \space \lnot Q(x_o) \qquad \qquad \exists-elim(3,5-16)} \\ 18. \forall x\lnot Q(x_o) \qquad \qquad \forall-intro(4-17)$

From the last version I changed the domain on the variables to be seen easier.

Question 1: I think I can change the domain to the second premise because they are two different domains, right?

Question 2: Lines 12 - 15, is this valid?

Question 3: For lines 4 - 7, I said $x_o$ is arbitrary so it can cancel out the for all statement. Is it valid to do it like I did for 6 and 7?

Comment: Can you use Law of Excluded Middle ?

Comment: I think you forgot variable $x$ in many places.

Comment: We can't use that law, only natural deduction rules, sadly. But when I mention $c$, I am referring to a specific element from the $\forall$ statement. In line 13 I can say I found the specific element by using the $\exists x$ assigning $Q(c)$ to $Q(x)$. Is that proper or is there something wrong with my way about this?

Comment: I see. But how are you using $\lor$ **Intro** in line 12 ? How does your $\lor$ **Intro** rule look like ?

Comment: Whoops! This should be an or elimination on line 12! Then line 12 would reference (5,6-7,8-11). Would that make the proof make more sense?

Comment: Line 5 is incorrect, because in line 2, Universal quantifier is not the _main logical connective_.

Comment: Why are you introducing an Existential quantifier in the last line? Aren’t you supposed to derive a statement with a Universal quantifier ?

Comment: I see! My mistake! I'm going to work on this and post another edit of the solution I will get.

Comment: Fixed now. I changed the domain. Is that valid for me to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113213/discussion-between-f-zer-and-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 6. ¬() ∨∀() ∀−(2,4)

That line is incorrect. In order to apply **$\forall E$**, Universal Quantifier needs to be the *main logical connective*.

> 16. ¬()∨−(8−11,12−15)

To use **$\lor E$**, a statement whose *main logical connective* is a disjunction needs to appear in previous lines; I cannot see such statement there.

A possible proof could be:
$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall\,Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall\,Intro}\colon #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists\,Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I}\colon #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land\,Intro}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land\,Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor\,Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to Intro}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I}\colon #1 \\}
\def\fi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\bot\,Intro}\colon #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I}\colon #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP}\colon #1 \\}
\def\X#1{\qquad\mathbf{\bot\,Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE}\colon #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{1.\,\forall xP(x)\\
2.\,\forall x\lnot Q(x) \lor \forall xQ(x)\\
3.\,\exists x(P(x) \to \lnot Q(x))
}{
  \fitch{4.\,[a]}{
    \fitch{5.\,\forall x \lnot Q(x)}{
     6.\,\lnot Q(a) \Ae{6}
}\\
    \fitch{7.\,\forall x Q(x)}{
     \fitch{8.\,[b]\,P(b) \to ¬Q(b)}{
       9.\,P(b) \Ae{1}
       10.\,\lnot Q(b) \ie{8,9}
       11.\,Q(b) \Ae{7}
       12.\,\bot \fi{10,11}
}\\
13.\,\bot \Ee{3,8-12}
14.\,\lnot Q(a) \X{13}
}\\
15.\,\lnot Q(a) \oe{2,5-6,7-14}
}\\
16.\,\forall x~\lnot Q(x) \Ai{4,15}
}
$

Comment: +1.  In my opinion, it would help the reader if you can add which rule you applied in each step.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @Taroccoesbrocco ! I was going to do just that :-)

Comment: Wow! Great proof! Sorry, I didn't see the chat about this problem...

Comment: No problem, @M__. Glad to help.